# CSS - Nav a tags have underline in Safari

Tags: html, css, wordpress, safari

The `<a>` tags on my nav bar have a link-underline which only shows up on Safari. How do I get rid of it? I've already got `text-decoration: none;` which should remove it but its not. Never seen that before -

[image]

The purple line is the border-bottom , it's the immediate black underline that I need to remove.

Here's my code as it stands -

```css
header {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

nav {
overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 999;
}

nav a {
  color: #000000;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 15px 5px 15px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
}

nav a:link {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration-line: none;
}

nav a:nth-of-type(1):hover {
  border-color: rgb(255, 29, 142);
}

nav a:nth-of-type(2):hover {
  border-color: rgb(133, 52, 146);
}

nav a:nth-of-type(3):hover {
  border-color: rgb(255, 128, 55);
}

nav a:nth-of-type(4):hover {
  border-color: rgb(0, 182, 223);
}

nav a:nth-of-type(5):hover {
  border-color: rgb(63, 190, 150);
}

nav a:nth-of-type(6):hover {
  border-color: rgb(255, 222, 32);
}

nav a:hover {
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<header>
<nav>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(4); ?>#particle-slider">Home</a>
    <a href="#what">What we do</a>
    <a href="#who">Who we are</a>
    <a href="#partners">Who we work with</a>
    <a href="#contact">Say hello</a>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(70); ?>">Blog</a>
</nav>
</header>
```

Comment: why do you need `border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;`?

Comment: @IlyaBursov For the color-coded underline.

Answer (score 1):

Just figures it out, bit embarrassed putting it as an answer but I was thrown a little by the fact it was only showing the line in Safari.

```
nav a:hover {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: i think it would be better to use !important because that way it will not get rendered by other UI in future

Answer (score 1):

Its always better to use it this way,

```
  nav a:hover 
 {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none! important;
  }
```